# How to code Levy Flight formula in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am rebuilding a Matlab program, Binary Cuckoo Search algorithm proposed by Rodrigues [here](http://zeus.inf.ucv.cl/~bcrawford/MII-748-METAHEURISTICAS/Papers_BinaryMH/BCS-%20A%20Binary%20Cuckoo%20Search%20algorithm%20for%20feature%20selection.pdf).

My question is how do I code the following formula?

```
x(i,j,t) = x(i,j,t-1) + a ⊕ Levy(λ)
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you look for `.*` instead of the **Hadamard product** sign. But since `a` seems to be a scalar, it's just like writing `*`, so I'm not sure what is the problem you encounter.

Comment: Thank you for responding my question. My question is how do I code/compute Levy(λ)?

Answer (score 1):

Levy flight in this article defined as a power law distribution, so what you need is to generate random numbers from this distribution, and you can use the [Inverse transform sampling method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) to do this. In this method, you generate random numbers from a uniform distribution U~(0,1] and convert them to any other distribution using it's CDF (if known).

In Matlab you would write:

```
N = 1000; % no. of random numbers to generate...
x = rand(N,1); % from a uniform distribution
gamma = 2; % scale parameter for the distribution (as in the article)
s = (1-x).^(-1/gamma); % s has a power-law distribution
```